# CSS Horizontal menu centre

Tags: html, css

i have this CSS Code for my nav menu:

```
#cssmenu ul { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu li { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu a { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu ul {list-style: none;}
#cssmenu a {text-decoration: none;}
#cssmenu {height: 50px; background-color: #f36f25; box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
-webkit-transition: color .15s;
   -moz-transition: color .15s;
     -o-transition: color .15s;
        transition: color .15s;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {color: #666666; }
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -90px;
    width: 180px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
   -moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
     -o-transition: all .3s .1s;
        transition: all .3s .1s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 65px;
    visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul:before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-color: transparent transparent rgb(250,250,250) transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul > li { position: relative;}
#cssmenu ul ul a{
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    padding: 5px 8px 7px 16px;
    display: block;
-webkit-transition: background-color .1s;
   -moz-transition: background-color .1s;
     -o-transition: background-color .1s;
        transition: background-color .1s;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {background-color: #f36f25;}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -16px;
    left: 206px;
    padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    text-align: left;
    width: 160px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s;
   -moz-transition: all .3s;
     -o-transition: all .3s;
        transition: all .3s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; left: 196px; visibility: visible;}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover{
    background-color: #f36f25;
    color: rgb(240,240,240);
}
```

i need to make the sub menu box move up a little more so you can see the small arrow on top on the orange part of the menu (main bit) and also make it full page width as it is but make the links/text centred on the page

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dQnjt/

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `float` and add `text-align: center` to the parent `ul`:

```
#cssmenu ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; }

#cssmenu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

And just reduce the top value on hover:

```
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 55px;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dQnjt/1/

Comment: excellent - thank you, how about with this fiddle, can i make it so the background colour fits the whole height of the orange bit? : http://jsfiddle.net/dQnjt/6/

Comment: You can do it by adding more padding so that the total height of the link (with the padding), matches the one of the `li` -> http://jsfiddle.net/dQnjt/7/

Comment: aha yes - perfect. is it possible to make it keep the hover colours on the main bar when the sub menu is open?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add  `ul:display:table; margin:0 auto;`, this will center the floated elements in it.

Answer (score -1):

I have added a Position: relative to the the following:

```
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -90px;
    width: 180px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
   -moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
     -o-transition: all .3s .1s;
        transition: all .3s .1s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
    visibility: visible;
    position:relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dQnjt/5/

Comment: You've killed the transition effect.